# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gets' memcache GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I have a simple Python program that uses GAE, and I am using GAE's memcache module to make sure that I do not screw up when updating the cache:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache

class NewPost(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("newpost.html")

    def post(self):

        #update cache for the front page
        val, unique = memcache.gets(FRONT_PAGE_KEY)
        for p in val:
            logging.warning(p)
```

Now this code should run without problem, but instead when I use the method post, it blows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
    response = self._internal_error(e)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pedro/google_appengine/hw6/blog.py", line 172, in post
    val, unique = memcache.gets(FRONT_PAGE_KEY)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gets'
INFO     2014-05-08 13:36:49,525 module.py:639] default: "POST /blog/newpost HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This makes no sense at all, specially because I know that memcache has a method called `gets(key)`:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/

Based on my research on stackoverflow I found this discussion:

- [App Engine Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Stock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896801/app-engine-python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-stock)

And so I have flushed my cache and deleted all my local DB's content, but I am still getting the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to check the documentation more closely; the module functions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions, differ from the `Client` class methods: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken: the `memcache` module does *not* have a `gets` function. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions).

`gets` is a method of the memcache `Client` object: again, see [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_gets).

Comment: Alright, your answer led me into a path that ultimately culminated the solution for my problem ! 
If you would be so kind, can you ask this link to your answer? 
http://neopythonic.blogspot.pt/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html It really explained everything and I got some examples as well! I will select it right away once the waiting time for selecting answers ends!